# Invoking HashSet.Add(item) in Linq vs foreach loop

Tags: c#, linq

Need help in following code segment:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var customers = new HashSet<Customer>();
    var action = new Action(() =>
    {
        var innerCustomers = new Customer[] 
        { 
            new Customer { CustomerID = 1, CustomerName = "C 1" }, 
            new Customer { CustomerID = 2, CustomerName = "C 2" }, 
        };

        innerCustomers.Select(c => customers.Add(c)); //doesn't work

        foreach (var customer in innerCustomers) 
            customers.Add(customer); //works fine
    });

    action();
}
```

`innerCustomers.Select(c => customers.Add(c));` does not seem to be working in terms of inserting records in the "customers" collection however, "foreach" down below that line works fine. Anybody has any idea why it's not working in linq? I know i am not selecting anything out of the select method

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Comment: Linq is not a modification- but query-tool.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You `Select` it, but don't do anything with the result. Because of LINQ's lazy evaluation (it generates the results on-demand through an `IEnumerable`) it just won't get executed. Use the `foreach` loop, it's the cleanest possible solution.

(The other solution is to use a `List<Customer>` instead and call `ForEach` on that... but unless you have a really good reason for wanting to use a method with a callback, there's no advantage.)

**Edit:** Actually, if all you're doing is adding elements to the `HashSet`, the cleanest possible solution is [`UnionWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342097.aspx):

```
customers.UnionWith(innerCustomers);
```

Comment: thanks, i totally forgot about the lazy loading :); as soon as i called .ToList(), it started loading the collection.

Comment: @MoizDhanji:  In general, LINQ is _expected_ to be free of side effects.  One would typically _expect_ a list when calling `ToList`.

Comment: @minitech: "UnionWith" is what i just used. i came back on the browser and saw you suggested the same thing :)

Comment: @Austin: "ToList" was just used for the time being just to see whether or not it works. thanks for the info.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but if you have to use Select, then you can do this:

```
innerCustomers.Select(c => { customers.Add(c); return c; });
```

Comment: As minitech mentioned, it won't work because of lazy loading.